# WordNet configuration failure: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions

Tags: installation, wordnet, nixos

I am attempting to install WordNet on NixOS. When attempting to run `$ ./configure`, I run into the following error.

```
$ ./configure
...
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
```

This appears to be a failure of the configuration script as no `Makefile` is generated from the `Makefile.in`.

I have searched for and installed many packages that I thought might contain the 'Tcl configuration definitions', including installing almost all the packages shown by `$ nix-env -qaP '*' --descriptions` which appeared to have something to do with `Tcl`, but to no avail.

What is a Tcl configuration? **How can I satisfy what is required by WordNet's configure script?**

Comment: Can't help with this specific issue but is there any reason you are not using [wordnet expression](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/misc/wordnet/default.nix) distributed with nixpkgs? Perhaps it could give you some clues as to how to build your custom version unless it's a completely different wordnet package?